# How can I inline images to the product description section for a registered brands using an Amazon MWS or a flat file?

Tags: amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

How to add inline images to the product description section for a registered brands using an [Amazon MWS](https://developer.amazonservices.com) or a flat file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're the registered brand owner, you'll want to use [enhanced brand content templates](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/help.html?itemID=202134820&language=en_US&ref=pa_202134820_cont_202102950) and I'm not aware of any place to modify those except directly at seller central.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently I'm using EBC templates. But I know people who use Salesforce to add/update their products and I think Salesforce uses some API or XML formatting like `<![CDATA[` to achieve this.

Comment: I thought they had removed the ability to use HTML for product descriptions, but maybe not.  You could format an html image tag and wrap it with CDATA and see what happens.   We use seller central for this type of thing.   You could always contact MWS support. https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/contactus.html

Comment: I asked MWS support, and they have no plans to release an API for EBC templates :(

Comment: :(  that's too bad.